# Constructing a string_view from a range of chars

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view

While a `span` can be constructed from a range, a `string_view` cannot be constructed from a range of chars.

Thus, for example, the following code is required:

```
// assume chars_span is a span of chars
std::cout << std::string_view(chars_span.data(), chars_span.size());
// or:
std::cout << std::string_view(chars_span.begin(), chars_span.end());
```

Instead of a simpler *range-syntax* that is not supported:

```
std::cout << std::string_view(chars_span);
```

Is there a reason for not having a constructor for `string_view` that accepts a range of chars, or was it just overlooked or not considered important enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[P1391r3](https://wg21.link/p1391r3) proposed this, though this was dropped in the version that was eventually adopted for C++20: [P1391r4](https://wg21.link/p1391r4). The reason for the drop unfortunately is completely absent from the paper (indeed, the paper does not even mentioned that it was dropped).

However, a follow-up paper, [P1989R0](https://wg21.link/p1989r0) presents the issue as what happens if we had a type like this (I modified the example slightly):

```cpp
struct buffer {
    buffer() {};
    char const* begin() const { return data; }
    char const* end() const { return data + 42; }
    operator string_view() const {
        return string_view(data, data + 2);
    }
private:
    char data[42];
};
```

Here, `buffer` is convertible to `string_view`. But the way in which it is convertible to `string_view` differs in the way in which `string_view`'s range constructor would do it (the former gives you two chars, the latter gives you 42). As far as I am aware, nobody has actually pointed out the existence of such types.

Nevertheless, the direction was to ensure that those types continue to just work, so the new paper has a more complicated set of constraints for that particular constructor.

---

A more interesting example would be something like:

```cpp
using ci_string = std::basic_string<char, case_insensitive_traits>;

ci_string value = "Hello";
std::string_view sv = value;
```

Any kind of straightforward range-based reasoning would allow the conversion from `ci_string` to `std::string`. A `ci_string` is a perfectly good contiguous range of `char`, without any weird conversion issues like the `buffer` type from earlier. But while `ci_string` should be convertible to `basic_string_view<char, case_insensitive_traits>`, we probably wouldn't want to avoid it being convertible to just normal `string_view`. That's unlikely to be intended, so it's something that we need to try to guard against.

This case is much more motivating for me than the `buffer` case.

Comment: I believe a similar issue can be presented for any function that gets a range, e.g. the constructor of `span` that gets a range.

Comment: That's terrifying. I'd be dying (of fear) if I had to take those eccentricities into consideration.

Comment: @AmirKirsh `span` didn't exist before C++20, so it's not an issue.